# Comparision of two positive invertible elements in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a,b$ are any two positive invertible elements in $A$. Must there exist $s,t>0$ such that $sa\leq b\leq ta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $c=a^{-1/2}ba^{-1/2}$.  Then $c$ is positive and invertible.  Thus there exist constants $s,t>0$ such that $s\leq c\leq t$ (namely, $t=\max\sigma(c)$ and $s=\min\sigma(c)$), and therefore $sa\leq b\leq ta$.

Comment: Firstly, the spectrum is compact, so $\max$ and $\min$ are achieved.  Now given $x\in A$ positive, write $s=\min\sigma(x)$ and $t=\max\sigma(x)$.  Then $x-s$ is self-adjoint, and $\sigma(x-s)=\sigma(x)-s\subset[0,\infty)$, so $x-s\geq0$.  A similar argument shows that $t-x\geq0$.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help